# pandas - plot according to groupby index level

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this simple dataframe `df`:

```
City,H
AMS,1.1
AMS,0.8
AMS,0.9
BOS,0.9
BOS,0.7
BOS,0.6
BOS,0.8
```

I would like to sort the `H` columns according to each `City`, and then plot each `City` index with a different color. So far I started by grouping and sorting:

```
d = df.groupby('City').apply(lambda x: x.sort('H', ascending=False))
```

Then, since I would like to plot the `H` values for each `City` according to a sort of ranking, I add a column called `subindex` as:

```
d['subindex'] = d.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
```

The resulting dataframe is:

```
       City    H  subindex
City                      
AMS  0  AMS  1.1         1
     2  AMS  0.9         2
     1  AMS  0.8         3
BOS  3  BOS  0.9         1
     6  BOS  0.8         2
     4  BOS  0.7         3
     5  BOS  0.6         4
```

The format is what I wanted, but I can't figured out why the column `City` appears twice. Now the problem is plotting, for each `City`, the `H` values according to the `subindex`. I tried:

```
for i, group in d:
    group.plot(x='subindex', y='H')
```

receiving the following `ValueError`:

```
for i, group in d:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: the iterable returned from the df are the columns, your df is no longer a `groupby` but a multi-indexed df, so you want `d.index.get_level_values(0).unique()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `d` is no longer a `groupby` object it is a multi-indexed df which is why you get the error:

```
In [61]:
for col in d:
    print(col)

City
H
subindex
```

this is what `d` is now:

```
Out[52]:
       City    H  subindex
City                      
AMS  0  AMS  1.1         1
     2  AMS  0.9         2
     1  AMS  0.8         3
BOS  3  BOS  0.9         1
     6  BOS  0.8         2
     4  BOS  0.7         3
     5  BOS  0.6         4
```

If you had not called `apply` on the `groupby` object then you could access the `groups`:

```
In [69]:
g = df.groupby('City')
g.groups

Out[69]:
{'AMS': [0, 1, 2], 'BOS': [3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

You could've iterated over the `groupby` object correctly as before:

```
In [71]:
for i, group in g:
    print(i)
    print(group)

AMS
  City    H
0  AMS  1.1
1  AMS  0.8
2  AMS  0.9
BOS
  City    H
3  BOS  0.9
4  BOS  0.7
5  BOS  0.6
6  BOS  0.8
```

As such what you want to do now is to use the index levels to filter your df and plot them:

```
for city in d.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    d[d['City']==city].plot(x='subindex', y='H')
```

yields following plots:

[image]

and

[image]